# Setting DSCP value on specific outgoing traffic in OS X with pf

Tags: networking, mac-osx, qos, pf, dscp

I want to set DSCP value on specific traffic coming out of an OS X machine.
I think the right way is to use pf, but I can't figure how to write the rule correctly.
I've tried something like this but when I try to load the file there is a syntax error:

```
pass out proto udp from any to any port 4321 set tos 0x20
```

Any idea of the right syntax ?

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea of the right syntax ?

OpenBSD’s PF *for Mac OS X* is mostly outdated, broken, rotten.

You're trying syntax that is used in modern OpenBSD's PF version.
Meanwhile before they changed it in OpenBSD, `set-tos` could be applied only in a `scrub`-rule — [OpenBSD 4.4 has it](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-4.4/pf.conf) in its `man pf.conf`, check it out.

Back to "[OpenBSD’s PF for Mac OS X is mostly outdated, broken, rotten](https://etcinsider.com/blog/2016/02/28/openbsd-pf-for-mac-os-x-is-mostly-outdated/)". Since OpenBSD 4.4 was the first version with support of `scrub … set-tos` we can conclude that Apple ported PF's version < 4.4 (say, 4.3) that still's being shipped with pretty recent macOS releases. I have no idea whether they apply any bug fixes, but answer to your question would be "*wrong OS for doing that with PF*".

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer.
Do you see another way to set DSCP value on outgoing traffic in OSX ?

Comment: Reminds me of https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372695/23761